# .NET Core 5.0 Singleton access to Configuration and HttpContext

Tags: .net, .net-5

I am little lost and looking for some help.
I have a singleton "Tools" class that works fine when I was just starting up with the Configuration via:

```
        public Tools(IConfiguration configuration) 
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Key = Configuration["NothingImportant"];            
    }
```

Which is started in the Startup.cs as

```
services.AddSingleton(new Tools(Configuration));
```

This works fine. However, I needed to add a method from a older .net standard app that used HttpContext.Current.User.Identity. So, it appears I should be able to change to:

```
        public Tools(IConfiguration configuration, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) 
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Key = Configuration["NothingImportant"];
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
```

and be able to access the accessor? However, I cannot figure out how to initialize this from startup and have both the configuration and the httpcontext?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add HttpContextAccessor you should add

> services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

to your `Startup` class, and and then you should be able to use `IHttpContextAccessor` injection.

And you can use service provider delegate to inject required service in the startup configuration:

> services.AddSingleton(serviceProvider => new Tools(Configuration, serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>()));

Comment: I did. This is likely due to my inexperience, but how do I initialize the singleton? If I add the injector to the constructor, I cannot construct the new Tools class without passing in something? What would solve for X for example: services.AddSingleton(new Tools(Configuration, X));

Comment: just use the service provider delegate to put the required service to your service like
`services.AddSingleton(serviceProvider =>
                new Tools(Configuration, serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>()));`

Comment: No luck. Both are undefined. =(

Comment: Not sure if this is a good idea? But this does work:             var test = new HttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddSingleton(new Tools(Configuration, test));